# Magento2: How to override widget template

Tags: magento2, widget

There is widget.xml in CatalogWidget module. Inside the widget.xml there is

```
        <parameter name="template" xsi:type="select" required="true" visible="true">
            <label translate="true">Template</label>
            <options>
                <option name="default" value="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" selected="true">
                    <label translate="true">Products Grid Template</label>
                </option>
            </options>
        </parameter>
```

What is a proper way to change the template file for the widget?

Answer (score 15):

you can extend the widget in your module.

To do that your module has to depend on the module where the original widget is defined (see sequence in the module.xml).

Then you create a widget.xml in your etc dir.

The key is, not to use the widget.xsd (there are many fields required that you do not need for extending) but the widget_file.xsd.

Here is an example to add a template to the static block widget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget_file.xsd">
    <widget id="cms_static_block">
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="template" xsi:type="select">
                <options>
                    <option name="option_id" value="Your_Module::view/form.phtml">
                        <label translate="true">Your Template</label>
                    </option>
                </options>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Here is another example with a container config, to allow the template for specific containers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget_file.xsd">
    <widget id="products_list">
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="template" xsi:type="select">
                <options>
                    <option name="slider" value="Vendor_Module::product/widget/content/slider.phtml">
                        <label translate="true">Products Slider Template</label>
                    </option>
                </options>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
        <containers>
            <container name="content">
                <template name="slider" value="slider" />
            </container>
            <container name="content.top">
                <template name="slider" value="slider" />
            </container>
            <container name="content.bottom">
                <template name="slider" value="slider" />
            </container>
        </containers>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Comment: I’ve tried creating a module that uses your widget.xml file and I get this error


`Invalid Document 
Element 'label': This element is not expected.
Line: 34`

The line 34 this error is referring to is in vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/etc/widget.xml

Can you try creating a module and implementing your solution to include a template in that widget? I think you may get the same error as me. If you do I will submit an issue on github. If not at least I will know I am doing something wrong.

Comment: hm, we are using this in an actual project for a product slider and it still works. Are you sure you are using the widget_file.xsd and that your xml structure is correct? Maybe try validateing your widget.xml against the widget_file.xsd.

Comment: It works for cms_static_block but not for the `products_list` widget. If you changed the id parameter on the widget node to products_list you will likely see the same error I am seeing.

Comment: actually, in our module, whe are extending the products_list widget to create a really lightweight product slider module (added as example to my answer). I don't think it will solve your problem, but we had to add the container config so that the template is allowed for the containers defined in the original widget

Comment: Looks like the container config missing from my widget.xml file was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant! It looked daunting at first, but it actually isn't that bad. I was able to build off this and add a custom boolean field to the product list widget, which controls sorting by a custom product attribute!

Comment: I had to add `<widget id="products_list" class="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" is_email_compatible="true" placeholder_image="Magento_CatalogWidget::images/products_list.png" ttl="86400">`.

Answer (score 8):

You can replace the grid.phtml where you call the widget

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" title="Our Products" products_count="8" template="Namespace_Modulename::product/widget/content/grid.phtml" }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom theme and copy the .phtml file to it, and make your changes.

`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog_Wiget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml`

Comment: Ok, but Im looking a solution that I can override the phtml inside my custom modul. To override in some xml file or something. Is it possible?

Comment: Magento will automatically load your phtml file from your module if it is placed in the correct folder, as I show above.  There's no XML changes needed to override a phtml file.

Comment: But Im looking other way then overriding that phtml in the way you mentioned. I need to do that in the scope of my custom module, I dont want to put any files to a theme.

Comment: Template files for widgets go in `<module>/view/frontend/templates/` and you would specify the file in your XML the same way CatalogWidget does. Even if you are extending CatalogWidget and your template is `<module>/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml`, the file in your custom module directory would take precedence.

Comment: "you would specify the file in your XML the same way CatalogWidget does" what do you mean by that? what XML? Copying template to my module with same path as in Magento_CatalogWidget and adding sequence node to module.xml simply doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error: Invalid Document Element 'label': This element is not expected. Line: 34 with products_list
This worked for me (**Magento 2.0.4**) **widget.xml** file in your custom module:

```
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget id="products_list">
        <label translate="true">Catalog Products List</label>
        <description translate="true">List of Products</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="template" xsi:type="select">
                <label translate="true">Template</label>
                <options>
                    <option name="slider" value="Vendor_Modul::product/widget/content/slider.phtml">
                        <label translate="true">Slider</label>
                    </option>
                </options>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
        <containers>
            <container name="content">
                <template name="slider" value="slider" />
            </container>
            <container name="content.top">
                <template name="slider" value="slider" />
            </container>
            <container name="content.bottom">
                <template name="slider" value="slider" />
            </container>
        </containers>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case I had to add only the `label` tag (widgets > widget > parameters > parameter > label) and then it worked. So the `containers` is not required.

Answer (score -1):

Ive created a preference for the widgets block class which makes the template path relative to the modules directory.

di.xml:

```
<preference
    for="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList"
    type="Vendor\Module\Block\CatalogWidget\Product\ProductsList" />
```

Class:

```
use Vendor\Module\Block\CatalogWidget\Product;

class ProductList extends \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductList {

}
```

Now the template in 
 `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml` is used instead of `Magento/CatalogWidget/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml`

Comment: I tried with this step but its not working.