# Magento 2: Override grid.phtml file from custom module

Tags: magento2, module, template-override

I am new to magento development can you help me how to override grid.phtml which resides in

`vendor\magento\module-catalog-widget\view\frontend\templates\product\widget\content\grid.phtml`

I need to customize this template from my module. but i am not understand how to override this file, where to put and all.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the `grid.phtml` where you call the widget like below

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" title="Our Products" products_count="8" template="Namespace_Modulename::product/widget/content/grid.phtml"}}
```

> Reference: [Magento2: How to override widget template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97396/magento2-how-to-override-widget-template/101924)

Edit:

You can override this template by coping `grid.phtml` file in below path.

New file path for your theme: `mytheme/Magento_CatalogWidget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml`

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: where i can put this code

Comment: Where you call your widget in Magento Admin.

Comment: is there any way i can override this programatically?

Comment: You can do it on theme level. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: is this work on cutom module/themes?

Comment: Yes, it is working with Custom themes. You just need to place grid.phtml in the shared path.

Comment: I am doing a module, so is this work? because after i put this path it is not working

Comment: This is for theme, for module extend, you can use the answer explained in the reference link I've given in my answer.