# How to override Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml widget template in custom Module?

Tags: magento2.4.1, widget, template-override

I want to override grid.phtml in custome module without using preference.I have tried this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97396/magento2-how-to-override-widget-template) but it does not work for me.

> widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget_file.xsd">
    <widget id="products_list">
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="template" xsi:type="select">
                <options>
                    <option name="grid" value="Vendor_Module::product/widget/content/grid.phtml">
                        <label translate="true">Products Grid Template</label>
                    </option>
                </options>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
        <containers>
            <container name="content">
                <template name="grid" value="grid" />
            </container>
            <container name="content.top">
                <template name="grid" value="grid" />
            </container>
            <container name="content.bottom">
                <template name="grid" value="grid" />
            </container>
        </containers>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and copypaste the exact code you have tried?

Comment: I have added code. check it.

Comment: You have a typo in file name `widegt.xml` :-). Did you actually named the file like that or is it a typo here on the forum?

Comment: this typo mistake is is just here.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1. Create di.xml file at app/code/Vendor/Module/etc into your custom module**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductsList" />
</config>
```

**step2. Create a block file ProductsList.php at app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Product to extend the widget class**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product;
class ProductsList extends \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList
{
}
```

Copy the related template file and put into your custom module with related Path

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml

to

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml

Make sure another module has not used the same preference in di.xml

Hope it helps.

---

If you've found my answer useful, please give"Kudos" and "Accept as Solution"

Comment: i have mentioned in my question that i want to override it without using preference

Comment: I dont think it can possible without it. please google if you can find other way